# Django won't load admin dashboard css with ngnix

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, nginx

I have a problem that has been holding me up in development for 1 week and I can't get out of it by seeing other users' answers. My project consists of a backend in Django and a frontend in React, the whole application is Dockerized and is served using ngnix. Now with the current configuration the Django css is not loading, what am I doing wrong? I thank everyone for the help.

**settings.py**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('DigitalMapping.urls')),
path('test', test, name='test'),
path('notificationCompletedOperation', NotificationCompletedOperation, 
name='notificationCompletedOperation'),
path('notificationErrorOperation', NotificationErrorOperation, 
name='notificationErrorOperation'),
path('', include('notifications.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
   FROM python:3.8.5
   WORKDIR /backend
   COPY ./ ./
   RUN pip install --upgrade pip
   RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
   RUN python manage.py collectstatic
   ENV PYTHONPATH ./backend
```

**default.conf**

```
upstream django {
server django:8002;
}

server {
listen 8080;

location / {
root /var/www/react;
}

location  ~ ^/(api|admin)/ {
proxy_pass http://django;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

  if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    #
    # Om nom nom cookies
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    #
    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X- 
    Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    #
    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
  }
  if ($request_method = 'POST') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X- 
 Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
 }
 if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X- 
 Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
 }
 }

    location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    }

 location /media/ {
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
 }

 }
```

**my Project**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t84T.png)

Comment: Without any knowledge of Django, I would suggest checking if your static files are served as static (good), or are the static file requests also sent to Djange. (In NodeJS you would need to tell the App that CSS and images come from public)

Answer (score 0):

you could try the below sequence -

more context:
https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/

before starting gunicorn call the collectstatic command to create the folder with the admin css in it:

```
./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

note where it writes out the files as that will need to match the below alias. The output location is the `STATIC_ROOT` as defined in the Django `settings.py` file.
"164 static files copied to '/app/backend/django_static'"

Ensure you have this location in your nginx conf with the alias corresponding to the output location. Here we map the Django `STATIC_URL` to the `STATIC_ROOT`:

```
location /django_static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /app/backend/django_static/;
}
```

Mount that file into the frontend container in the docker-compose.yml. It should match the alias above. With the below volume specified in frontend and backend container, the frontend container is able to read the static files that the manage.py command in the backend container output.

```
volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/backend/django_static
```

Now those static files will be used to style the django admin page.
If it is not working, ensure to watch the webserver logs as they will tell you where it is looking for the admin.css files if it can't find them